# Не верный путь к контроллеру

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, razor

При нажатии на кнопку удаления происходит перенаправление по неправильному адресу.
Название контроллера: DealController.
Название метода: DeleteDeal.
В адресной строке появляется вот такой адресс: https://localhost:44387/%3Ca%20href=%22/Deal/DeleteDeal/1%22%3ERemove%3C/a%3E

```
<td>
    <a href='@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "DeleteDeal", "Deal", new { id = deal.Id} )' class="fa fa-trash")></a>
    </td>
```

Comment: А зачем вы запихнули `@Html.ActionLink` внутрь тега `A`?

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий. Понял свою ошибку :)